# Is it possible for ColumnTransformer or Pipeline to return a dataframe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, preprocessor

I am doing my preprocessing with sk learn and want to use ColumnTransformer to add several steps together.

This is my code:

```
## numerical features   
numerical_transformer = make_pipeline(
        KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3), 
        StandardScaler()
    )

## Categorical features
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

categorical_transformer = make_pipeline(
    SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'),
    OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
)

## Combine both steps 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('numerical', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('categorical', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])
```

To fit it to the train data, i.e. learn the mode, etc, and to actually do all the steps above, i.e. filling the missing values, etc, I use:

```
# Fit the training (!) data to the pipeline
preprocessor.fit_transform(train_df2)
```

Now, I want to do some feature engineering and selection after the preprocessing and therefore it would be handy that the `preprocessor.fit_transform`-step, would return me a data frame, instead of an np array.

My question is, is that even a legit way to do it? Because most pipelines I've seen also add directly the model at the end of it and fit the data to the model. (In that case, it's perfectly okay if it "returns" a data frame, because I don't really get to see it, it'll be directly put into the model.)

I've tried it with:

```
# Fit the training (!) data to the pipeline
pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(train_df2))
```

But that took ages.
I just want to know if I'm doing anything wrong or if there's a different way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, I see two at the moment: "*How do I convert the output of a ColumnTransformer to a DataFrame*" and "*Why is this slow?*" What you're doing looks right, but if it's slow my guess would be that the `KNN` imputation is a bottleneck. If you want to convert the output to a DataFrame, it might be convenient to maintain the column labels somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I also believe that the kNN imputation is the bottleneck. 
Regarding to my questions: I think what I am really looking for is *how to convert the output of ColumnTransformer to a Dataframe*.